# connect to maria db with mauricio/postgresql-mysql driver in play2.5

Tags: database, scala, asynchronous, playframework, mariadb

is it possible to use mauricio/mysql-async driver in scala and play2.5 to connect to mariadb database? I am using jooq now with the mariadb-java-client currently.

Do you know of any async mariadb driver for scala/play, or oes any of you have maybe an example of config with the mysql-async driver from mauricio for mysql or mariadb?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use play-slick?

just by googling found successful examples:

- [Slick 2.x examples with MariaDB
  Raw](https://gist.github.com/fancellu/0f30e8f135404831288c)
- [Play framework, Slick and MySQL Tutorial](http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/) (it's mysql, but it should be easy do adapt to mariaDB)

Comment: I don't want to use slick, seems to heavy for me right now, I would like to have total control over SQL, it is also true that i'm new to play ans scala and jooq seems so much easier ... so I wil stick with jooq

Comment: never used jooq with play, so I think I can't help you on this one :(

Comment: no problem ... tnx for anyway, maybe I will switch to slick in future for now it seems a little bit to much for me :(

Answer (score 0):

If it's still relevant, have a look at [jasync-sql](https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql) (Disclaimer: I am working on it). It is a port of Mauricio lib that works with mysql so should work with MariaDB as well.

It is used like this:

```
  // Connect to DB
  Connection connection = new MySQLConnection(
  new Configuration(
    "username",
    "host.com",
    3306,
    "password",
    "schema"
  )
);
CompletableFuture<?> connectFuture = connection.connect()
// Wait for connection to be ready   
// ...    
// Execute query
CompletableFuture<QueryResult> future =             
connection.sendPreparedStatement("select * from table");
// Close the connection
connection.disconnect().get()
```

You can read more on the wiki: https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/wiki